# How to calculate the date of next Monday in PHP?

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to get a date that comes next Monday at night 00:01 am. I'm using the following lines:

```
date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime(**'next monday, 01:01am'**, strtotime(date("Y-m-d h:i:s"))))
```

This gives me the proper output:

> 2014-05-19 01:01:00

But if I try to write:

```
date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime(**'next monday, 00:01am'**, strtotime(date("Y-m-d h:i:s"))))
```

I'm getting:

> 1970-01-01 05:30:00

Please tell me what is wrong here.

Comment: you can use 24 hour format? hope it will work

Comment: There is no such hour as 0 AM, it's 12 AM.

Comment: Oops, thanks edvinas.me

Comment: 00:01 is morning, not night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>**00:01 am**</strike> is not correct Use **12:01 am**

Try this:

```
date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime('next monday, 12:01am', strtotime(date("Y-m-d h:i:s"))));
```

It will give you `2014-05-19 12:01:00`

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/152400)